# Is it possible to attach to a remote gdb target with vscode?

Tags: gdb, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to setup the configuration to attach to a remote C/C++ gdb target running gdbserver with visual studio code.  Is this currently supported?  If so, how do I get around these limitations:

1. The address and port options indicate that they aren't supported for C/C++.
2. I can force code to use the special remote enabled version of gdb, but its trying to run the target application locally and not connecting to the target gdbserver platform.
3. Will PowerPC remote targets be supported assuming I can solve #1 and #2?

Answer (score 20):

This is a bit late, but I just set this up right now. 
I'm debugging an linux application running on a remote ARM device

I installed the [Native Debug](https://github.com/WebFreak001/code-debug) extension for VS Code.

Here is my launch.json configuration

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "gdb",
        "request": "attach",
        "name": "Attach to gdbserver",
        "executable": "<path to exe relative to workspace root>",
        "target": "X.X.X.X:9999",
        "remote": true,
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}", 
        "gdbpath": "D:/gcc-ma/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gdb.exe"
    }]
```

So on my arm device running linux:

```
gdbserver localhost:9999 ./<application>
```

Then on windows, I attach to that server.

I have gdbpath set up because i need to use a version of gdb that understands arm. I got the correct windows binaries from [here](https://launchpad.net/linaro-toolchain-binaries)

I had lots of help along the way

- http://austinhanson.com/vscode-gdb-and-debugging-an-os
- https://github.com/WebFreak001/code-debug
- https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/78

Comment: I have a same problem, my device at 192.168.15.130 and did config {
            "type": "gdb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program (SSH)",
            "target": "./hello",
            "cwd": "/home/root/test1/",
            "ssh": {
                "host": "192.168.15.130",
                "cwd": "/home/root/test1/",
                "user": "root"
            } and not working ...

Comment: @ceiling cat   I have two followup questions.                                                       
Do we need to install the extension on remote machine or local machine ?  
Where will the source reside on the local or remote machine? I suppose the source and build both will be on the remote machine, right ?

Comment: the extension is on the local machine. The binaries were cross compiled locally so the source was also local. It's been a while so I cant remember a lot of the details.

Comment: the term `remote` becomes confusing because debugging over a local network means remote while debugging over the internet means remote as well. My question is how to establish a connection between gdb installed on GitHub codespace and gdbserver (alongside the program) installed on a local vscode?

Answer (score 0):

1. VS code (local) and gdb(remote) are installed
2. install ssh remote plugin
3. open your workspace in your Vs code using remote ssh coneection
4. In the vs_code debug tab, click the setting icon, it should open the launch.json / create one if doesn' exist
5. add following code in launch.json (edit binary, workspace root, process_id)

```js
{
       
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [      
            {
                "name": "(gdb) Attach",
                "type": "cppdbg",
                "request": "attach",
                "program": "${path to binary}",
                "processId": "${process id to attach to}",
                "MIMode": "gdb",
                "cwd":"${workspaceRoot}",
                "setupCommands": [
                    {
                        "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                        "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                        "ignoreFailures": true
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

6. Save changes, and click Green Start button on Run and Debug tab.

Comment: ProcessId does NOT have ```$``` in its value. It should be a quoted string like ```"processId": "31518",```.  Same with the "program" key - use the regular syntax of launch.json there.

You may also need to add the path to the debugger like ```"miDebuggerPath": "/home/utils/gdb-10.1/bin/gdb"```, for example.