# How to attach to remote gdb with vscode?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

I want to do remote C/C++ gdb debug with vscode. I use "Native Debug" extension where I do configuration. Here is my *launch.json* configuration

```
{
        "type": "gdb",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program (SSH)",
        "target": "./hello",
        "cwd": "/home/root/test1/",
        "ssh": {
            "host": "192.168.15.130",
            "cwd": "/home/root/test1/",
            "password": "",
            "user": "root"
}
```

And at target I run

```
gdbserver localhost:2000 ./hello
```

Unfortunately after I can't sill connect with remote device to debug. Is there someone with experience on configuring of this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to attach to a remote gdb target with vscode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38089178/is-it-possible-to-attach-to-a-remote-gdb-target-with-vscode)

Answer (score 34):

I found the answer of this question here:
[Is it possible to attach to a remote gdb target with vscode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38089178/is-it-possible-to-attach-to-a-remote-gdb-target-with-vscode)

Summary:

First you need to install the [Native Debug](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=webfreak.debug) extension for VS Code.

Then edit launch.json file and add:

```
{
    "type": "gdb",
    "request": "attach",
    "name": "Attach to gdbserver",
    "executable": "<path to the elf/exe file relative to workspace root in order to load the symbols>",
    "target": "X.X.X.X:9999",
    "remote": true,
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}", 
    "gdbpath": "path/to/your/gdb",
    "autorun": [
            "any gdb commands to initiate your environment, if it is needed"
        ]
}
```

Then you can restart the VS Code and start debugging.
Make sure there is no other client is connected to the gdb-server otherwise you will get time-out error.

Comment: I have tqo followup questions. 

Do we need to install the extension on remote machine or local machine ? 
Where will the source reside on the local or remote machine? I suppose the source and build both will be on the remote machine, right ?

Comment: @irsis it can be, but ususally it is opposite, since remote machine is regarded as production (or nearly production) https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Connecting.html#Host-and-target-files

Comment: I get a "Debugger requested kill" message when I try to connect, and the process I'm trying to debug aborts immediately

Answer (score 11):

You have to install gdbserver on the remote machine. E.g.

```
apt-get install gdbserver
```

start the gdbserver on the remote machine

```
gdbserver :1234 ./mybinary
```

pick any port you like - here `1234`

test the connection to gdbserver from your local machine by typing

```
gdb
(gdb) target remote myremotehostname:1234
```

trigger any gdb command to check whether it works - e.g. `c` (or `continue`) to continue running `mybinary`.

Put the following into your `.vscode/launch.json`

```
    {
      "name": "C++ Launch",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/mybinary",
      "miDebuggerServerAddress": "myremotehostname:1234",
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "externalConsole": true,
      "linux": {
        "MIMode": "gdb"
      }
    }
```

Or use the `"type": "gdb"` launch config as given in the other answer(s).

In order to get code browsing and stuff working, it's important to have the source directories in sync on the local and remote side. Use a network filesystem, manual copying, git triggers or anything like that to set this up.

Comment: Is there an advantage using cppdbg vs "Native Debug extension"? It's not clear to me why there are two extensions doing the same thing.

Comment: For anyone who got hung up on the first test step. 
If you only run "gdb" to test, you'll get no symbols.   
The gdb client also needs access to the exe with debug symbols.. 
e.g.     gdb /path/to/myapp
then (gdb) target remote myremotehostname:1234

Comment: Yeah I couldn't figure out why *Native Debug* exists when it seems to mostly duplicate the built in `cppdbg`. It is quite old though (7 years) so I imagine the author wanted some additional features. It still does have some extra features (e.g. LLDB support) but it would be nice if the author explained the differences in the Readme. Note there's also a dedicated extension for LLDB - [CodeLLDB](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vadimcn.vscode-lldb) which supports connecting to `lldb-server` *and* `gdbserver`! So there are at least 3 options!

Comment: `"request": "launch"` is required regardless of whether the remote gdbserver *launched* the remote process or whether it *attached* to an already running target. Don't change the config to `"request":"attach"` or it will prompt you for a pid from your *local* machine which is not relevant (bug??). I suspect *Native Debug* plugin is obsolete? I installed nothing. Will test this with a bare metal arm target soon and report back.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [{
    "type": "cppdbg",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/vmlinux", // for loading symbols from running program
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",

    // if you want to connect at entry point (requires remote program to start paused)
    "stopAtEntry": true,
    "stopAtConnect": true,

    "MIMode": "gdb",
    "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
    "miDebuggerServerAddress": "localhost:1234",
    "setupCommands": [{
      "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
      "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
      "ignoreFailures": true,
  }]
}]
}
```

Comment: Yup, works for me - you seem to have to use the `launch` rather than `attach` request, which makes no sense.

Answer (score -1):

1. VS code (local) and gdb(remote) are installed
2. install ssh remote plugin
3. open your workspace in your Vs code using remote ssh coneection
4. In the vs_code debug tab, click the setting icon, it should open the launch.json / create one if doesn' exist
5. add following code in launch.json (edit binary, workspace root, process_id)

```js
{
       
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [      
            {
                "name": "(gdb) Attach",
                "type": "cppdbg",
                "request": "attach",
                "program": "${path to binary}",
                "processId": "${process id to attach to}",
                "MIMode": "gdb",
                "cwd":"${workspaceRoot}",
                "setupCommands": [
                    {
                        "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                        "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                        "ignoreFailures": true
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

6. Save changes, and click Green Start button on Run and Debug tab.

Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/72580854/19317199

Comment: There is no info in your json file about remote gdb location and SSH connection itself.  How does it work?

Comment: Maybe there should be the"pipeTransport" section for SSH connection?

Comment: This doesn't attach to remote GDB, it just attaches to a process.