# How to pass source files to gdbserver

Tags: c++, gdb, vscode-debugger, gdbserver

I'm trying to debug a remote C++ application using.
My setup is two machines (1) `remote` (where the c++ application and `gdbserver` runs) and (2) `dev` where I like to debug from and where the *source code* is accessable.

Important: The `remote` **doesn't** contain the **source code** (And I can't add it to the `remote`).

The only please I have seen referring to this kind of setup is [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Server.html) using the `monitor` command. But I wasn't able to make sense of it.

- Is it possible to have the source code on one machine and the application running on the other?
- Using `gdb` on `dev` can I debug the application with source code support?
- Can it be achieved via **vscode**?

Answer (score -1):

> The remote doesn't contain the source code

That is the *usual* setup.

> The only please I have seen referring to this kind of setup is here using the monitor command.

Please correct your grammar, and note that the `monitor` command should only be used under rare circumstances, and likely has nothing to do with your problem.

> Is it possible to have the source code on one machine and the application running on the other?

Yes. That is how remote debugging usually works.

> Using gdb on dev can I debug the application with source code support?

Yes. That is exactly what remote debugging is. It just works.

> Can it be achieved via vscode?

[Probably](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54039501/50617), but I don't know much about `vscode`.

Comment: Sorry but `Probably` and `It just works` is really helping. Do you have something a bit more concrete?

Comment: @Daniel I've answered 2 or your 3 questions. Your problem is somewhere in `vscode` setup.